# Access UserControl elements/properties from main window in a WPF XAML PowerShell script

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell, powershell-4.0

I wrote the following `Test.ps1` PowerShell script to display a WPF GUI:

```
function LoadXamlFile( $path )
{
    [System.Xml.XmlDocument]$xml = Get-Content -Path $path
    $xmlReader = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNodeReader -ArgumentList $xml
    $xaml = [System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $xmlReader )
    return $xaml
}

# Main Window
$MainWindow = LoadXamlFile 'MainWindow.xaml'

# Page 1
$Page1 = LoadXamlFile 'Page1.xaml'
$MainWindow.Content = $Page1

$TextBox1 = $MainWindow.FindName('TextBox1')
# The following line fails because $TextBox1 is null
$TextBox1.Text = 'test'

$MainWindow.ShowDialog()
```

This script requires the two following XAML files:

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="MainWindow"
    Title="WPF Test" Height="200" Width="400">
</Window>
```

`Page1.xaml`

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Page1">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="23" Margin="0,-40,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="76"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The issue, as stated in my PowerShell code, is that I can't access UserControl elements/properties after adding the UserControl to the main window.
I know I can access it with `$Page1.FindName('TextBox1')` but is there a way to do it from the `$MainWindow` object?

Comment: Do you mean you need to access the elements from the $Page1 object? Not the $MainWindow object?

Comment: I mean that after adding the `$Page1` object into `$MainWindow.Content` I should be able to access TextBox1 from `$MainWindow` which is not the case with my current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a `FindName` in the `Content` of `$MainWindow`

```
$TextBox1 = $MainWindow.Content.FindName("TextBox1")
```

Comment: Oh I see, it works but usually when I need to access an element of the window, `$MainWindow.FindName("TextBox1")` is enough, do you think the previous `$MainWindow.Content = $Page1` is the root cause of the need to use `$MainWindow.Content.FindName("TextBox1")`? If so maybe there is a cleaner way to add a UserControl to my window?

Comment: $MainWindow is a `System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl`. If you do a `FindName` it will only search within that control. $MainWindow.Content is another, different `System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl`. So that is why it was not working.  Bit rusty on WPF so don't know any cleaner ways of doing it.