# Best practice to add a UserControl to a window in a WPF XAML PowerShell script

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell, powershell-4.0

I wrote the following `Test.ps1` PowerShell script to display a WPF GUI:

```
function LoadXamlFile( $path )
{
    [System.Xml.XmlDocument]$xml = Get-Content -Path $path
    $xmlReader = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNodeReader -ArgumentList $xml
    $xaml = [System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $xmlReader )
    return $xaml
}

# Main Window
$MainWindow = LoadXamlFile 'MainWindow.xaml'

# Page 1
$Page1 = LoadXamlFile 'Page1.xaml'

# Is there a cleaner way than the following line to add a UserControl object to the main window?    
$MainWindow.Content = $Page1

$TextBox1 = $MainWindow.Content.FindName('TextBox1')
$TextBox1.Text = 'test'

$MainWindow.ShowDialog()
```

This script requires the two following XAML files:

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="MainWindow"
    Title="WPF Test" Height="200" Width="400">
</Window>
```

`Page1.xaml`

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Page1">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="23" Margin="0,-40,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="76"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Is there a way to add the UserControl to my main window which would allow me to find elements with `$TextBox1 = $MainWindow.FindName('TextBox1')` instead of `$TextBox1 = $MainWindow.Content.FindName('TextBox1')`?

Is `$MainWindow.Content = $Page1` the right way to add a UserControl to my main window ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly, because UserControl has it's own [naming scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659(v=vs.110).aspx). If you added the usercontrol to mainwindow twice, which element should FindName method return?

However, you can write your own method, that traverse visual tree.
here is one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63157/LINQ-to-Visual-

```
    public static IEnumerable<UIElement> Descendants(this UIElement element)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as UIElement;
            if (child == null) continue;
            yield return child;
            foreach (var childOfChild in Descendants(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I understand why it cannot work. Interesting article about LINQ to Visual Tree, however I won't go into that amount of code.

Comment: You can simplify it to single method called Descendants() that traverse visual tree and returns IEnumerable using yield return. Its up to 10 lines of code, see my edited answer

Comment: Again, interesting piece of code, though it is C# code and I use PowerShell. I think it is ok to keep it in your answer as reference. I will accept your answer before the bounty ends, I'm just waiting in case someone has anything to add.

Comment: Ah, ok, I did not notice you don't have codebehind. Btw, why don't use just `$Page1.FindName`?

Comment: I'm aware of that option (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900141/access-usercontrol-elements-properties-from-main-window-in-a-wpf-xaml-powershell), actually I think I will end up using this solution. I just thought it might be "cleaner" to use the top level `$MainWindow` object to access elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this: `$MainWindow.AddChild($Page1)` if you prefer.

You could access the textbox by its index - but that's not really cleaner imo:

```
# $TextBox1 = $MainWindow.Content.FindName('TextBox1')
# $TextBox1.Text = 'test'
$Page1.Content.Children[0].Text = 'test'
```

I'm not sure what kind of improvement for your code you expect. It seems alright, apart from the fact that you are using PowerShell to manipulate a GUI - that's pretty much always the wrong way of doing things imo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will have a look at it and try your code sample. Also I'm aware that a scripting language isn't meant to do the same things than a programming language, I just intend to use it for administrative purpose.

Comment: Ok. Even so, I would encourage you to look for ways keep user interaction natively in PowerShell. An acceptable way to present data to users and even let them make choices might be `Out-GridView`. User input is usually best handled by writing commandlets with properly defined parameters.

Comment: Of course I agree with you, but the script I was writing at that time was designed to be used on a short period of time by end users, not power users who know how to use PowerShell.